# Advanced custom field - custom field of post object extracted only the first time

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 2 posttypes books and stores where stores is assigned as postobject for books.

bookcode and bookinfo are fields of posttype-book and storeurl is customfield of posttype-stores

what i am trying to do...based on the store selected in the dropdown in books, i want to display the store and the corresponding storeurl from posttype store for each book along with the book's bookcode and bookinfo.

in below all posts are displayed ...with correct storename bookcode & bookinfo for all posts but the storeurl is extracted correctly only for the lastpost how do i get it to extract for all posts correctly

```
<?php 
while (have_posts()): the_post();?>

<div class="bookindex">

     <div class="bookdata">
        <?php               
        $storelist = get_field('storelist');            

        foreach ($storelist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
        $storename = get_the_title($post->id);
        $storelink = strip_tags(get_field('storelink',$post->id));
        //var_dump($storelink);     
        ?>

        <div class="storename">
            <?php echo $storename;?>
    </div>

        <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>   

    <?php   
        $bookinfo = get_field('bookinfo',$post->id);
        ?>  

    <div class="bookinfo">
            <?php echo $bookinfo; ?>
    </div> 

    <?php
    $bookcode = get_field('bookcode',$post->id);
    ?>

    <div class="clickbtn">
            <a href="<?php echo $storelink; ?>">
                     <?php echo $bookcode; ?>
            </a>
    </div>

    </div>       
</div> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

***new code***

```
<?php 

while (have_posts()): the_post();   

?>
<div class="bookindex">

     <div class="bookdata">         
        <?php    
        $bookinfo = get_field('bookinfo',$post->ID);
        $bookcode = get_field('bookcode',$post->ID);

        $storelist = get_field('storelist');   
        $stores=array(); 
        foreach ($storelist as $store):
        $stores[] = array(
        'name' => get_the_title( $store->ID ),
        'link' => strip_tags( get_field( 'storelink', $store->ID ) )
    );
    endforeach; ;
        ?>
        <div class="storename">
            <?php echo $stores[$post->ID];?>
    </div>

    <div class="bookinfo">
            <?php echo $bookinfo; ?>
    </div> 

    <div class="clickbtn">
            <a href="<?php echo $stores[$post->ID]; ?>">
                     <?php echo $bookcode; ?>
            </a>
    </div>

    </div>       
</div> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

it doesn't return either the storename or the storeurl

Comment: comeon not a single reply

Comment: if i move the endeach below the click btn then too the storelink is not extracted for all except for last post plus the bookinfo and click btn are repeated more than once for each post of in books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `$storelink` inside the `foreach ( $storelist as $post )` loop, but not using it until you've ended the loop, meaning only the last $storelink defined will be available. If you need to accumulate a bunch of store names and titles you might consider something like:

```
$stores = array();
foreach ( get_field( 'storelist' ) as $store ) {
  $stores[] = array(
    'name' => get_the_title( $store->ID ),
    'link' => strip_tags( get_field( 'storelink', $store->ID ) )
  );
}
```

Then you'll have an array of stores to purchase the book that you can use to build the links (if I'm understanding your usage correctly; either way, the mystery of `$storelink` only being correct for the last item in the loop is because the variable is never used until after the loop).

**Edit:** Your updated version tries to reference specific array keys that don't exist; I'm afraid I may have confused things more with my array suggestion. If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, something like this should fit the bill:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <div class="bookindex">
    <?php
      // Since $bookinfo and $bookcode don't appear to change, we'll get them once and save it
      $bookinfo = get_field( 'bookinfo', $post->ID );
      $bookcode = get_field( 'bookcode', $post->ID );
    ?>

    <?php foreach ( get_field( 'storelist' ) as $store ) : ?>

      <div class="bookdata">
        <div class="storename">
          <?php echo get_the_title( $store->ID );?>
        </div>

        <div class="bookinfo">
          <?php echo $bookinfo; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="clickbtn">
          <a href="<?php echo strip_tags( get_field( 'storelink', $store->ID ) ); ?>"><?php echo $bookcode; ?></a>
        </div>

      </div><!-- .bookdata -->

    <?php endforeach; ?>

  </div><!-- .bookindex -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Edit 2:** Clearly I'm not getting exactly how you're looking to echo the links, but the answer to the original question ("why is `$storelink` only correct for the last iteration of the `$storelist` loop?") remains the same - the variable is being overwritten multiple times without anything being done with it in-between iterations.

Comment: steve i updated the code...using the modifications suggested by  u but now i it returns neither the storename or the storeurl.

Comment: it doesn't echo the storename or the store url now also it repeats the post numerpus times ..sending a screenshot http://s100.photobucket.com/user/littledevil2014/media/4-14-20149-30-13AM_zps9838c7b9.png.html

Comment: bookdata seems to repeat itself multiple time within a bookindex

Comment: answer for edit 2 : i m using the code u gave without any changes to echo the storename selected in the book post and then search the posttype stores for the storename and echo the corresponding storelink field

Comment: hey i got it sorted...i just changed the $store->ID to $store and it worked...thanx so much steve